# UiButton action method not working

Tags: ios7, uiview, notifications, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have a banner view that comes over navigation. I have added a custom button that i have added like:

```
- (id) initWithNotification:(JCNotificationBanner*)notification {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    isPresentedMutex = [NSObject new];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.iconImageView = [UIImageView new];
    self.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"];
    [self addSubview:self.iconImageView];
    self.titleLabel = [UILabel new];
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
    self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:self.titleLabel];
    self.messageLabel = [UILabel new];
    self.messageLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    self.messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
    self.messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self addSubview:self.messageLabel];

      // Button
      _detailDisclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [_detailDisclosureButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosure.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [_detailDisclosureButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];

//      _detailDisclosureButton.hidden = NO;
      [_detailDisclosureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(detailDisclosureButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [_detailDisclosureButton setEnabled:YES];
      [self addSubview:_detailDisclosureButton];

       UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer;
tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                        action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    self.notificationBanner = notification;
  }
  return self;
}
```

Here is what my draw context method is calling.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  CGRect bounds = self.bounds;

  CGFloat lineWidth = kJCNotificationBannerViewOutlineWidth;
  CGFloat radius = 10;
  CGFloat height = bounds.size.height;
  CGFloat width = bounds.size.width;

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
  CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);

  CGMutablePathRef outlinePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

  CGPathMoveToPoint(outlinePath, NULL, lineWidth, 0);
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(outlinePath, NULL, lineWidth, height - radius - lineWidth);
  CGPathAddArc(outlinePath, NULL, radius + lineWidth, height - radius - lineWidth, radius, -M_PI, M_PI_2, 1);
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(outlinePath, NULL, width - radius - lineWidth, height - lineWidth);
  CGPathAddArc(outlinePath, NULL, width - radius - lineWidth, height - radius - lineWidth, radius, M_PI_2, 0, 1);
  CGPathAddLineToPoint(outlinePath, NULL, width - lineWidth, 0);

  CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  CGContextAddPath(context, outlinePath);
  CGContextFillPath(context);

  CGContextAddPath(context, outlinePath);
  CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
  CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);

  CGPathRelease(outlinePath);
}
```

And my layout subview methods that arrange frame are like:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
  if (!(self.frame.size.width > 0)) { return; }

  BOOL hasTitle = notificationBanner ? (notificationBanner.title.length > 0) : NO;

  CGFloat borderY = kJCNotificationBannerViewOutlineWidth + kJCNotificationBannerViewMarginY;
  CGFloat borderX = kJCNotificationBannerViewOutlineWidth + kJCNotificationBannerViewMarginX;
  CGFloat currentX = borderX;
  CGFloat currentY = borderY;
  CGFloat contentWidth = self.frame.size.width - (borderX * 2.0);

  currentY += 2.0;
  if (hasTitle) {
    self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(currentX, currentY, contentWidth, 22.0);
    currentY += 22.0;
  }
  self.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(currentX, currentY, contentWidth, (self.frame.size.height - borderY) - currentY);
  [self.messageLabel sizeToFit];
  CGRect messageFrame = self.messageLabel.frame;
  CGFloat spillY = (currentY + messageFrame.size.height + kJCNotificationBannerViewMarginY) - self.frame.size.height;
  if (spillY > 0.0) {
    messageFrame.size.height -= spillY;
    self.messageLabel.frame = messageFrame;
  }
     _detailDisclosureButton.frame = CGRectMake(285,self.center.y-15,29,29);
}
```

My Button action method named `detailDisclosureButtonPressed` is not being called. Please help me out in this ?

Comment: What is `self` in `initWithNotification:`? Is userActionEnabled?

Comment: its an init method for banner. You can see "JCNotificationBannerView" from github. Yes userInteractionEnabled is enabled.